# What is the (middle length) sutta, where Buddha exposes a monk, who has an ignorant view of non-self?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras, non-self

In one sutta a monk was teaching, that there's something that is behind our existence, that is permanent (opposite of non-self). Buddha asked for this explicitely, got confirmed, and corrected the view. Which sutta it is?

Comment: @arthur Can you say anything else about which sutta you're looking for? Because a lot of suttas are about anatta.

Comment: @ChrisW, thanks for the help! Names of Monks were very useful. I clearly remember reading a sutta recently where Buddha knew (as he always does) that there was a monk who was spreading the idea, that there's a soul that never dies, i.e., is of non-selfness kind. Buddha asked him explicitly if there's anything of non-self kind, got a positive answer, asked whether he was teaching others about it, got positive answer, told monk that this is wrong, and explained the concept again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly [MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/horner), where the monk held:

> At one time the Lord was staying near Sāvatthī in the Jeta Grove in
> Anāthapiṇḍika's monastery. Now at that time a pernicious view like
> this had accrued to the monk called Sāti, a fisherman's son: “*In so
> far as I understand Dhamma taught by the Lord it is that this [same;
> identical; [anañña](https://suttacentral.net/define/ana%C3%B1%C3%B1a)]
> consciousness itself runs on, fares on, not another.*"

Note: I chose the translation of I.B. Horner to avoid the contradictory [eternalism](https://suttacentral.net/define/sassatav%C4%81da) of the other translators, who use words such as "transmigration" or add words that do not even exist in the sutta, such as "round of rebirths".

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. In https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/43770/17887 you posted a reference to https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books7/Buddhadasa_Bhikkhu_Anatta_and_Rebirth.pdf that reference has exactly the translation I was reading `Misguided man, to whom have you ever known me to teach the Dhamma in that way?..`, which points exactly to MN 38. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [MN 35](https://suttacentral.net/mn35/en/sujato), however the protagonist is not a bhikkhu but is a Jain:

> All the plants and seeds that achieve growth, increase and maturity do
> so depending on the earth and grounded on the earth. All the hard work
> that gets done depends on the earth and is grounded on the earth.
>
> In the same way, an individual’s self (attāyaṃ purisapuggalo) is form. Grounded on form they
> make good and bad choices. An individual’s self is feeling …
> perception … choices … consciousness. Grounded on consciousness they
> make good and bad choices.
>
> Aggivessana, are you not saying this: ‘Form is my self, feeling is my
> self, perception is my self, choices are my self, consciousness is my
> self’?
>
> Indeed, Master Gotama, that is what I am saying.